# How to cancel peer long-running tasks if one of them stops

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I have several long-running Task objects. I'd like them all to just keep running indefinitely. The job of one of these tasks is to self-monitor the system. If something happens outside of normal operating conditions, I'd like it to be able to stop running and somehow signal the other tasks to stop running as well. Is it enough to just use Task.WaitAny(), stop the one thread and the others will stop, or will those other Tasks keep running indefinitely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those Tasks will continue running, unless you explicitly handle cancellation.

The preferred method to handle this is using the new [cooperative cancellation support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx) in .NET 4.

The normal method would be to have a continuation on each task that runs when a task fails/faults.  It could then have a `CancelationTokenSource` that gets canceled.  Each task can occasionally check to see if it should abort because a cancellation is requested.

Comment: Thank you. It felt like a catch-22, but using a continuation Task to send the cancellation token is a great solution.